# Error Message when opening python program created with cx Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

I want to make a runnable program using python and cx_Freeze.

The script uses the csv, socket, ipaddress, threading and tkinter packages. 
When I open the tool I see the error message displayed below.

Is this a problem with imports? Or am I doing something wrong?

This is how my setup script looks like:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["tkinter","socket","csv","struct","threading","ipaddress"], "excludes": []}


# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"


setup(
    name = "CSV Tool",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Tool to work with data to create CSV to import with uCMDB",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("csv_tool.py", base = base)])
```

[image: Error Message]

PS: It is a win8.1 64 bit system with python3.4

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You appear to be using a 32-bit library, are you sure that everything else involved is 32-bit?

Comment: I don't know why there is this path in the error message... as you can see in the third line, my python is installed in another directory. c:\python doesn't exist...
I didn't install anything else than python3.4 and I don't use any other packages than the out of the box packages

Comment: OK, check your PYTHONPATH environment variable.  Run `cmd.exe` and type `set`.

Comment: This is a known issue with cx_Freeze. Download it from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) to get the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas commented, the cx_Freeze setup from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) helps to prevent the error.